# Sharepoint 2013 Site Title only show parent site

Tags: development, team-sites

I have a team site and am using the *Site Title* snippet, but I don't want that changing to show my subsite titles. For example here is an example team site hierarchy we are using for our companies departments:

- IT (Home)

  - Forms
  - Procedures
  - About
  - Contact

When I click on contact or forms, etc it changes the top link to Contact instead of Information Technology. We want this to function like a regular website if possible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a construct as such should do it, see more here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.projectproperty.property.aspx).

```
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
```

Comment: This will also change to show subsites. That's what he didn't want

Comment: I get a "Sorry something went wrong" error when placing that in.

Comment: Ok - I added in the <!--SPM: --> and it worked. One thing though, I want to get the Root site, not the current site. Is that possible, and the link to it?

Comment: Use this: `<asp:SiteMapPath SiteMapProvider="SPSiteMapProvider" id="GlobalNavigationSiteMap1" RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="true" SkipLinkText="" NodeStyle-CssClass="ms-sitemapdirectional" runat="server"/>`. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/bf9c549e-619d-47b9-b01c-786af0800b09/sitecollection-nametitle-in-masterpage?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy